# Html5 button gets :hover when it shouldn't

Tags: android, css, html, cordova, hover

I'm making a simple flashcard application for Android. In the app I have four buttons - one to show answers and three to grade. When I press the "show anser" button, this button disappears (i use .hide()), and the "grade" buttons appear (.fadeIn()). The problem is that the grade button that was in the place of the show answer button gets highlighted.

The "show answer" button:

[image]

Then I press the button:

[image]

And that's what appears:

[image]

Instead of what should appear:

[image]

Any ideas how to sort this problem out?

Comment: Does it revert to the correct style when you press somewhere else?

Comment: When I press somewhere else it reverses to the correct style, and then when I press somewhere else again, the third button is orange again.

Answer (score 0):

1) why do you have a "hover" state if developing for touch screens?
2) check in webinspector what is going on.